# Target_User.Link not working

Tags: email, workflow, email-template, user

I am trying to use the Workflow target user merge field {!Target_User.Link} but it's not displaying anything. Even though all the other fields work fine.

For example : {!Target.User.FirstName} and {!Target.User.LastName} work fine.

Any other ways i can get the link for the Target user? Just need to be able to click it and which will take me to the record detail page.

Comment: Target.User or Target_User ? typo?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i think i foudn the answer.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i8k4AAA

"The "Target_User" thing is still only a Beta feature as of May 2015, so I expect that there will be not be any "bug" report or update from product development on this. "